# Gallery view inside ViewPager

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-fragments

I implemented a ViewPager inside my app (according to this recent blog entry: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html).

One of my views inside my ViewPager is a ListView with a gallery as its header view. (Looks pretty much like the early version of the Android market back in 2008). 
However, the gallery is not scrollable now. Instead of wiping through the images in my gallery I'm scrolling through the different views inside the ViewPager.

I need a workaround to fix this. Any hints?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure your listitem is clickable i.e. does it receive the click event. by default the listItem's parent receives the event and the event is not passed down.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So...  just to get this right...  you are saying you are putting a gallery view inside of a list view inside of a view pager.

Is that right?

Seriously, um, don't do that. :}

Anyway the problem you have is that the ViewPager watches for vertical movements to swipe between the pages.  It is taking the vertical movements, so you can't do vertical movements in the gallery to swipe in it.

Comment: Listviews inside a ViewPager are not that uncommon. And a GalleryView as a header view is also not that uncommon (see the early version of Android Market) but in general your answer is correct. It is possible to grab a touchevent if the user is swiping through my gallery but after thinking for a while on this problem I came to the conclusion that this would be a usibility fail :)

Comment: I currently have a Gallery in a ViewPager and the gallery works except the scrollbars never appear back once they have disappeared :/

Comment: how about a GridView inside a ViewPager? i can't swipe it unless i put my finger on an empty space on it?